# Intuitive way to make something like a member function for an enum class (C++11)

Tags: c++, c++11, enums

Near as I can tell the ideal thing I'm looking for is outside of the C++11 spec, which would be something like where if I otherwise had something like an enum class where the core of it would look this something like this:

```
enum class Color { RED, ORANGE, YELLOW, GREEN, CYAN, AZURE, BLUE, MAGENTA };
```

I ideally would have wanted to have (non-virtual) member functions such that I could define something like this:

```
Color Color::complement() const
{
  switch(*this) {
    case RED:return CYAN;
    case ORANGE: return AZURE;
    case YELLOW: return BLUE;
    case GREEN: return MAGENTA;
    case CYAN: return RED;
    case AZURE: return ORANGE;
    case BLUE: return YELLOW;
    case MAGENTA: return GREEN;
  }
}
```

Of course, the C++11 spec doesn't allow you to define member functions for enum classes, so this is not possible.

Now strictly speaking, I don't *really* require my `complement` function to actually be regular member function, specifically, but if it could not be, then I ideally would want it to somehow still be specified using `Color::` for scope resolution.  Even a static member function would have been fine, taking a `Color` argument as a parameter, but again... C++11 does not allow you to have even static member functions in an enum class.

One option that had occured to me was to sacrifice this the preference for explicitly specifying `Color::` in the name, and define a function at the same level as the `Color` enum as follows:

```
Color complement(Color orginal) 
{
  switch(orginal) {
  ...
  }
}
```

The biggest problem I have with this approach is that this complement function is not bound to the class namespace of `Color`, and although argument checking assures that it won't be used in another context, I feel that code that utilizes the function would be clearer to the reader of the code if the function were called via `Color::complement`, which in my opinion reads much more idiomatically than simply `complement`.  Further, such encoding of the type into how one calls this function is actually enforced by the compiler itself (the ideal, in my opinion, since it does not necessitate that the function name be anything more than a predicate to be very clear to one who is reading the code on what the function's purpose is and how it is to be used), and the name cannot get inadvertently deprecated if the underlying types should change, which is my biggest problem with trying to use a naming scheme that somehow encodes the names of datatypes into the names of the identifiers themselves.

I had briefly also considered just using namespaces, like so:

```
namespace Color
  enum  { RED, ORANGE, YELLOW, GREEN, CYAN, AZURE, BLUE, MAGENTA };
  int complement(int orginal)
  {
    switch(original) {
     ....
    }
  }
}
```

Which would allow me to specify colors as `Color::RED`, `Color::BLUE`, etc, as well as be able to specify something like `Color::complement(x)` to get the complement of the color contained in x, but this approach does not have strong type checking that an enum class does.  If I used an enum class inside of the Color namespace itself, then I would be forced to specify colors as `Color::additional_name::RED`, etc... instead of just `Color::RED`, which is how I want to be able to specify them.

C++ does not allow me to have both an enum class called `Color` and a namespace `Color`, so there is no way to syntactically achieve what I am after that way either.

So... is there a way to achieve the scoping that I would like, with the strong type-checking that I want, or am I just hosed, and expecting more of the language than what it is really designed to do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It isn't exactly what you're asking for, but you could overload an operator for the `enum class`, and use that to complement it.

```
enum class Color { 
  RED,
  ORANGE,
  YELLOW,
  GREEN,
  CYAN,
  AZURE,
  BLUE,
  MAGENTA
};

Color operator~(Color c) {

  switch(c) {

    case Color::RED:     return Color::CYAN;
    case Color::ORANGE:  return Color::AZURE;
    case Color::YELLOW:  return Color::BLUE;
    case Color::GREEN:   return Color::MAGENTA;
    case Color::CYAN:    return Color::RED;
    case Color::AZURE:   return Color::ORANGE;
    case Color::BLUE:    return Color::YELLOW;
    case Color::MAGENTA: return Color::GREEN;

  }
}

~Color::RED == Color::CYAN
etc...
```

Comment: This amounts to the same thing as just naming a function `complement` that takes a Coior argument... although for some reason, I find the approach of using operator overloading more appealing than just using a predicate function name.  Perhaps because of what is generally implied by the tilde operator that may not be implied by the english word 'complement'.

Comment: Operators are just functions, but they're more fundamental to types and the language, as opposed to free form which could take any number of arguments.  At least for this specific instance, I think `operator~` expresses the semantics okay.

Answer (score 7):

**No, for the reasons you give.**

But I don't see why you're so hung up on making this a member function. Enum or no enum, I don't see the value in making it a member anyway. It *should* be a free function in the same enclosing namespace.

Let ADL handle the name lookup for you. What's wrong with this?

```
Color comp{complement(Color::RED)};
```

Comment: @JasonS overload resolution picks up function that are declared in the namespaces of the arguments, sparing you a fully-qualified call (`Color::complement(Color::red)`). That's Argument-Dependent Lookup.

Comment: If the argument to complement were a variable rather than a constant, it may not have any explicit reference to its argument being a Color, and the predicate 'complement' by itself may be too vague to tell what the function was supposed to do simply by reading how the function is called.  As I said above, I would prefer to not have to use that style, because I feel that it may become less obvious what the function actually does when reading code where it is called without having to explicitly encode type information into the function name itself, which won't be enforced by the compiler.

Comment: @markt1964 I'd say that if you ever get to a point where you don't know what one of your variables is, that's the problem...

Comment: @markt1964: There's a slippery slope argument in there somewhere. When you read your code you should know what type your variables have, to the extent that you need to (and where this extent lies is what you're getting worried about here, I think). (This is the problem with overuse of `auto`; yeah, Sutter, I'm looking at you...) Taking strange approaches and hacking odd designs into your codebase just because you think one day it might not be perfectly obvious what `complement(myColorVariable)` does (which seems disingenius unless your variable names are truly awful) is an odd decision, IMO.

Comment: Ultimately, the argument I had against that style was that for code like `auto highlight=complement(foreground)` might not be immediately obvious if there was another complement method declared for some other type.  This could be rectified by encoding type information into the variable name such as `auto highlight_color=complement(foreground_color)`, but such naming can only be a coding convention, and is not enforced by the compiler.   Either a member function or static member function would have had ideal semantics for what I wanted to achieve. Neither is permissible in C++, so this is moot.

Answer (score -1):

I didn't test this, sorry: 
inside the named namespace, use ::Color::RED, that is using the global namespace.